# Building an undirected graph from depth-first sorted node list in Python

Tags: python, tree

I have an array called `nodes` that contains a list of `Node` objects. The list is sorted in depth-first order. I have a function called `build_undirected_tree` that assigns the `parent` value and creates a list of `children` for each `Node` in the list.

I'm not satisfied with the need for using the `idx` array to circumvent Python's lack of pass-by-reference on primitive-type arguments and I'm wondering if there's a conceptually simpler way to accomplish the same thing.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, child_count):
        self.child_count = child_count

'''
This is a depth-first iterator. The weird `idx` array is used because
integers cannot be pass-by-reference.
'''
def node_iterator(nodes, idx=None, parent=None):
    if idx is None:
        idx = [0]
    node = nodes[idx[0]]
    yield (node, parent)
    for i in range(node.child_count):
        idx[0] += 1
        yield from node_iterator(nodes, idx, node)


def build_undirected_tree(nodes):
    for (node, parent) in node_iterator(nodes):
        node.parent = parent
        node.children = []
        if parent is not None:
            parent.children.append(node)

nodes = [...]
# Populate nodes from a file.
build_undirected_tree(nodes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get a similar result by creating and passing around an iterator on the `nodes` list:

```
def node_iterator(nodes, nit=None, parent=None):
    if nit is None:
        nit = iter(nodes)

    node = next(nit)
    yield (node, parent)

    for i in range(node.child_count):
        yield from node_iterator(nodes, nit, parent=node)
```